# Reupload SHA1 and SHA256 with same value in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have an Android project and integrate with Firebase.

I see there is configuration to input **SHA1** and **SHA256**. I wonder, what if i re-upload them with same value? Should i re-download the `google-services.json` again?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you download the first google-services.json file? Is it from Firebase console?

Comment: Yes, it is from Firebase console.

Comment: If there are no configuration changes in your app, no need to re-download the google-services.json file again.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports 2 types of certificate fingerprints:

- SHA-1: Used to create OAuth 2 client and API key for your app
- SHA-256: Used for configuring Firebase Dynamic links

If you use these Firebase products, you need to generate these certificate fingerprints and add them on Firebase console > Project settings > Your app section.

Note that if a combination of package name and SHA-1 OR SHA-256 already exists in another project, you can't use it anymore. You will see an error message similar to below:

> Another project contains an OAuth 2.0 client that uses this same SHA-1
> fingerprint and package name combination